# Classifying numbers which have same labels and same neighborhood in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, indexing, grouping, classification, cell-array

If `A` is a matrix which its second column(`A(:,2)`) represent labels of different `"categories"`:

```
A =     
    { 3x2 cell}    [  1]
    { 2x2 cell}    [  2]
    { 3x2 cell}    [  3]
    { 4x2 cell}    [  4]
```

and each `"category"` include some `"numbers"` which classified in some `"sub-categories"`. It means `A{i}(:,2)` are labels of `"sub-categories"`. For instance:

```
%copy-paste A into MATALB

A{1} =  {[2.5]    [1];  % sub-category is [A]
         [1.49]   [2];  % sub-category is [B]
         [0.35]   [3]}; % sub-category is [C]

A{2} =  {[3.8]    [1];  % sub-category is [A]
         [1.09]   [2]}; % sub-category is [B]

A{3} =  {[6.95]   [1];  % sub-category is [A]
         [7.04]   [2];  % sub-category is [B]
         [2.85]   [3]}; % sub-category is [C]

A{4} =  {[5.5]    [1];  % sub-category is [A]
         [3.1]    [2];  % sub-category is [B]
         [6.76]   [3];  % sub-category is [C]
         [9.8]    [4]}; % sub-category is [D]

A=A.'

A{1,2}=1;
A{2,2}=2;
A{3,2}=3;
A{4,2}=4
```

The goal(`B`) is to classified `"numbers"` **(2.5, 1.49, etc.)** in accordance to their `"sub-category"` labels **(A,B,C and D)**. Moreover, the most important point is that the classifying should be done only for those `"sub-categories"` which are neighbors to each other. It means, those `"numbers"`  should be selected in a same group which they have same `"sub-category"` and they were searched only in next and previous `"categories"` **(1,2,3 and 4)**. Therefore, in our example we would like to get:

```
%  First column shows the number
% Second column shows the sub-category
%  Third column shows the category

  % For [2.5] which has sub-category "A" or better to say "[1]", 
  % it has only one neighborhood in category [2]:
B{1}=
  [2.5]    [1]     [1]
  [3.8]    [1]     [2]

  % For [1.49] which has sub-category "B" or it is better to say "[2]", 
  % it has also one neighborhood in category [2]:
B{2}=
  [1.49]   [2]     [1]
  [1.09]   [2]     [2]

 % For [2.5] which has sub-category "A" or it is better to say "[1]", 
 % it has two neighborhood in category [2] & [3]:
B{3}=
  [2.5]    [1]     [1]
  [3.8]    [1]     [2]
  [6.95]   [1]     [3]

 % For [1.49] which has sub-category "B" or it is better to say "[2]", 
 % it has two neighborhood in category [2] & [3]:
B{4}=
  [1.49]   [2]     [1]
  [1.09]   [2]     [2]
  [7.04]   [2]     [3]

 % For [2.85] which has sub-category "C" or it is better to say "[3]", 
 % it has one neighborhood in category [4]:
B{5}=
  [2.85]   [3]     [3]
  [6.76]   [3]     [4]

 % For [6.95] which has sub-category "A" or it is better to say "[1]", 
 % it has two neighborhood in category [2] & [4]:
B{6}=
  [6.95]   [1]     [3]
  [3.8]    [1]     [2]
  [5.5]    [1]     [4]

 % For [5.5] which has sub-category "A" or it is better to say "[1]", 
 % it has one neighborhood in category [3]:
B{7}=
  [5.5]    [1]     [4]
  [6.95]   [1]     [3]

 % For [9.8] which has sub-category "D" or it is better to say "[4]", 
 % there is no number with the same label:
B{8}=
   [9.8]   [4]     [4]

 % And finally, for [0.35]; although, there are some number with the same label, 
 % there is no neighborhood in the next category( means category 2):
B{9}=
   [0.35]   [3]    [1]
```

In order to clarify the problem, I was asked to add some explanation. Therefore, firstly, we should search the `"sub-category"` labels of each number. Then, among those numbers which have the same label, we need to check whether they have any neighbor in next or last `"category"` with the same `"sub-category"` or not.
It would be great if the proper code probably be written with `cellfun` or `bsxfun` functions instead of using a loop as it is probably more efficient. Thanks

Comment: Please check your B. Also please clarify what do you mean by, *"Moreover, the most important point is that the classifying should be done only for those "sub-categories" which are neighbors to each other. It means, those "numbers" should be selected in a same group which they have same "sub-category" and they were searched only in next and previous "categories" (1,2,3 and 4)".* Next and previous with respect to what? For example, in B{4}, you include categories `1,2,3` but you don't include category `3` in B{2}, why? Also,  where did `5.5` go. It is nowhere to be seen in `B`.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar My bad. I should explain more. I will amend it ;)

Comment: In the meantime, this is some code to get you started: `t=cell2mat(vertcat(A{:,1}));
t = sortrows(t,2);
idx = cumsum(diff([0;t(:,2)])>0);
idxn = histc(idx,unique(idx));
C = mat2cell(t,idxn,size(t,2))`. Check `C` at the end. You are welcome to add this code to the question and edit it if you feel it simplifies the question/lessens your task.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll check that, as well.

Comment: I have edited the question such that now `A` can be copy-pasted. If it is inappropriate, feel free to roll back the edit.

Comment: Well done! I am completely agree with that :)

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar I suppose that it's more clear now! thanks for your time